# Sitecore Solr Master Slave

Tags: solr, content-search

I am working with Sitecore 8.2 with XDB and using Solr as a search provider. I have setup Master and Slave instances and configured Cores on both the instances.

Now I have couple of questions:
1) Which Cores need to be configured on Solr Master instance and which cores need to be configured on Slave.
2) while setting up replication, which Cores need to replicated from Master to Slave. Do I only need to setup replication on cores required by CD as per https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up_and_maintaining/search_and_indexing/indexing/search_indexes_required_in_a_scalable_environment

Currently I have configured following cores in Master and Slave:
sitecore_web_index, 
sitecore_master_index, 
sitecore_core_index,
sitecore_analytics_index, 
social_messages_web, 
social_messages_master, 
sitecore_marketing_asset_index_master, 
sitecore_marketing_asset_index_web, 
sitecore_testing_index, 
sitecore_suggested_test_index, 
sitecore_fxm_master_index, 
sitecore_fxm_web_index, 
sitecore_list_index, 
sitecore_marketingdefinitions_master, 
sitecore_marketingdefinitions_web,

Thanks in advance.